# How do you print a variable in a string that is followed by alphanumeric characters in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a filename to appear like this:

focus131021a.wav

I've declared the date as a variable:

```
$DateFilename = get-date -format "yyMMdd"
```

However, I can't get that variable into a string while keeping the last "a" character. Here are some of the many failed trials...

```
PS C:\script> $FileName3 = "focus'$DateFilename`a.wav"
PS C:\script> echo $FileName3
focus'131021.wav
PS C:\script> $FileName3 = "focus$DateFilename'a.wav"
PS C:\script> echo $FileName3
focus131021'a.wav
PS C:\script> $FileName3 = "focus$DateFilename`a.wav"
PS C:\script> echo $FileName3
focus131021.wav
PS C:\script> $FileName3 = "focus$DateFilename'aa.wav"
PS C:\script> echo $FileName3
focus131021'aa.wav
PS C:\script> $FileName3 = "focus$DateFilename'a.wav"
PS C:\script> echo $FileName3
focus131021'a.wav
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to use formatting:

```
$filename3 = 'focus{0:yyMMdd}a.wav' -f (get-date)
```

Otherwise you end up with insane escape sequences, nested quotation marks, or a mess of a string addition.

Comment: Thanks. Just so I understand the logic as I'm learning powershell. -f calles the function (get-date) where the items in {} are passed as a variable? What is the significance of the 0:

Comment: `formatstring -f arguments` is a shortcut for `String.Format(formatstring, arguments)`. The `{0}` signifies the first argument, which in this case is `get-date`. The parentheses just tell Powershell to run the command before substituting.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this using the OP's original approach:

```
$DateFilename = get-date -format "yyMMdd"
$FileName3 = "focus${DateFilename}a.wav"
```

You can use {} around a variable name inside a double-quoted string to demarcate the variable name from other text.

Comment: This works in the simple case, but blows up when trying to use properties, or hashtables.

Comment: @Eris If you're using properties then you're not really doing simple variable interpolation. You're doing expression evaluation. In that case `"focus$(get-date -f yyMMdd)a.wav"` works just fine. I don't see *any* need to use the `-f` operator in this case.